# registerNotificationActions is not a function in ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, action

Trying to get action click event in push notification, for this i have user below method

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import PushNotificationAndroid from 'react-native-push-notification';

PushNotificationAndroid.registerNotificationActions(actions);

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('notificationActionReceived', function (
      action,
    ) {
      console.log('Notification action received: ' + action);
      const info = JSON.parse(action.dataJSON);
      if (info.action == 'Accept') {
        // Do work pertaining to Accept action here
      } else if (info.action == 'Reject') {
        // Do work pertaining to Reject action here
      }
     
    });
```

While sending push notification, i am getting below error:

TypeError: _reactNativePushNotification.default.registerNotificationActions is not a function. (In '_reactNativePushNotification.default.registerNotificationActions(actions)', '_reactNativePushNotification.default.registerNotificationActions' is undefined)
r

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. Apparently PushNotificationAndroid.registerNotificationActions(actions) is no longer required and has been removed.

When I commented out that line my code started working again.

Here is the link to the change log I found this in:
https://nicedoc.io/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

If you scroll down to section
[4.0.0] 2020-07-06
Breaking changes
you'll find more info.

You may need to make more changes depending on your specific project.